# Auto-update web application

Tags: asp.net, auto-update

I'm in a very bad situation: I need to maintain asp.net web application hosted in an environment on which I don't have any access. For every small intervention I need to go personally which includes checking procedures since it'as a government agency.

I was wondering if there is some way to partially of full update an asp.net web application from the application himself of from some other web-based tool.

I don't have neither remote desktop, vpn and all this should be done through http.

Thanks...

Comment: Can your server see the internet?  Or at least your version control system?

Comment: Yes server on which the application is hosted can see internet, but due to a security issues I need to do everything through http.

Comment: So you will (most certainly) add a security leak over HTTP if you open up your app this way, or am I missing somthing here?

Comment: Not necessarily, click once application can auto-update himself against url from which was downloaded (if newer version is copied on the server with higher assemblies version). I was thinking if such solution could work for web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea to give your app the privileges to write on the disk.
A better solution would be to have a back end process (service) running on the same machine which would check some server of yours if there is a new version available and deploy it on a apropriate occasion. 
But of course this proces must have privileges to write to disk and access the internet (or external network).
As it is a goverment agency I don't think they will be keen on such a solution.